# How do i add a button to back to Main Menu (another .lua file)?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, composer-php

This game is something like killing mosquito. This is the level 1 file. When player tap the bee, game over will be displayed. When time's up, game over will be displayed. Total mosquitoes killed will be displayed at the end. I'm very very new to corona and to game development.
My question is:

1. Where to put in function to go back to main menu via "touch"? What is the code for it?
2. i'm using composer. So i tried composer.gotoScene("menu") but that doesn't seems to work. Error.

Thanks in advance for any help given. Here is part of the code:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
local physics = require("physics")
local widget = require "widget"
physics.start()
rand = math.random( 20 )

local slap_sound = audio.loadSound("Sound/slap2.mp3")
local ow = audio.loadSound("Sound/ow.mp3")
local buttonSound = audio.loadSound("Sound/sound2.mp3")
local back

--local mossie_sound = audio.loadSound("Sound/mossie.mp3")
local count={total1=0,total=0,touch=0,life=3}

local background = display.newImageRect( "Images/bg.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    background.anchorX = 0
    background.anchorY = 0
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0

local total=display.newText("Score : 0",display.contentWidth * 0.5, 20, "Arial", 26)
      total:setTextColor(000000)

local time_remain = 30
local mossie
local bee
local shade
local gameOverScreen
local winScreen
local gameIsActive = false

local countdown=display.newText(time_remain ,display.contentWidth * 0.9, 20, "Arial", 26)
countdown:setTextColor(000000)

local life = display.newText("Life : 3 " ,display.contentWidth * 0.5, 50, "Arial", 26)
life:setTextColor(000000)

local pauseBtn = display.newImage("Images/pause.png")
     pauseBtn.x = display.contentWidth * 0.1
     pauseBtn.y = display.contentHeight - 450

local resumeBtn = display.newImage("Images/playb.png") 
    resumeBtn.x = display.contentWidth * 0.1
    resumeBtn.y = display.contentHeight - 450


     local gameOver = function()
     composer.removeScene("level1")  //scene cannot be removed???
     gameIsActive = false
     physics.pause()
     gameOverScreen = display.newImage("Images/gameover.png",400,300)
     gameOverScreen.x = 160
     gameOverScreen.y = 240
     gameOverScreen.alpha = 0
     transition.to(gameOverScreen,{time=500,alpha=1})
     total.isVisible = true
    total.text="Score : "..count.touch
    total.x = 160
    total.y = 400
        botwall.isVisible = false
        mossie.isVisible = false
        bee.isVisible = false
        life.isVisible = false
        countdown.isVisible = false
        pauseBtn.isVisible = false
        resumeBtn.isVisible = false

     end



    local collisionListener=function(self,event)
        if(event.phase=="began")then
            if(event.other.type=="mossie")then
                audio.play(ow)
                count.life=count.life-1
                    if(count.life==0) then
                        gameOver()
                    end 
                event.other:removeSelf()
                event.other=nil
            else
                event.other:removeSelf()
                event.other=nil
            end

        end

    end


    local function countDown(e)
        time_remain = time_remain-1
        countdown.text = time_remain
    end

    local checkTimer = function()
        if(time_remain == 0) then
        gameOver()
        end
    end

    function killIt(e)
        if(e.phase == "ended") then
            gameOver()
        end
    end

    --spawn Bee
    local function newBee(event)

        bee = display.newImage("Images/lebah.png")
        bee.x = 60 + math.random( 160 )
        bee.y = -100
        bee.type="other"
        physics.addBody( bee, { density=1.4, friction=0.3, bounce=0.2} )
        checkTimer()

        bee:addEventListener("touch",killIt)

    end

    ---whenMossieIsTouched
    function onTouch(mossie)
        audio.play(slap_sound)
        count.touch=count.touch+1
        total.text="Score : "..count.touch
        mossie.target:removeSelf()
        --print("total"..mossietouchcount)
    end

    ---spawn Mossie
    local function newMossie(event)    
        --audio.play(mossie_sound)
        total.text="Score : "..count.touch
        life.text="Life : "..count.life
        mossie = display.newImage("Images/biasa.png") 
        mossie.x = 60 + math.random( 160 )
        mossie.y = -100
        mossie.type="mossie"
        mossie:setFillColor(255,0,0)
        physics.addBody( mossie, { density=0.3, friction=0.2, bounce=0.5} )
        mossie.name = "mossie"
        --checkTimer()
        mossie:addEventListener("touch",onTouch)

    end 

    local bottomWall = function()
        --botwall=display.newRect(0,display.contentHeight,display.contentWidth*2,10)
        botwall=display.newImage("Images/tangan.png")
        botwall.x = 160
        botwall.y = 500
        botwall:setFillColor(22,125,185,255)
        botwall.type="botwall"
        botwall.collision=collisionListener
        physics.addBody(botwall,"static",{ density=100.0, friction=0.0, bounce=0.0} )
        botwall:addEventListener("collision",botwall)
    end

    local gameActivate = function()
        gameIsActive = true
    end



    local gameStart = function()
    local gametmr = timer.performWithDelay(1000, countDown, 0)
    local dropMossie = timer.performWithDelay( 1000 , newMossie, -1 )
    local dropBee = timer.performWithDelay( 1800 , newBee, -1)

    local pauseGame = function(e)
        if(e.phase=="ended") then
            audio.play(buttonSound)
            physics.pause()
            timer.pause(gametmr)
            pauseBtn.isVisible = false
            resumeBtn.isVisible = true
            return true
        end
    end

    local resumeGame = function(e)
        if(e.phase=="ended") then
            audio.play(buttonSound)
            physics.start()
            timer.resume(gametmr)
            pauseBtn.isVisible = true
            resumeBtn.isVisible = false
            return true
        end
    end

    pauseBtn:addEventListener("touch", pauseGame)
    resumeBtn:addEventListener("touch", resumeGame)
    resumeBtn.isVisible = false
    bottomWall()
    gameActivate()


    end

    gameStart()
    return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the scene is called "menu.lua" when you try to use the `composer.gotoScene("menu")`

First make sure you require the libraries at the top

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local widget = require( "widget" )
```

Then add a listener that will handle the button events

```
local function handleButtonEvent( event )
    if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
        composer.gotoScene ("menu")
    end
end
```

And then create the button

```
local myButton = widget.newButton
{
    left = 100,
    top = 200,
    id = "myButton",
    label = "Default",
    onEvent = handleButtonEvent
}
```

**EDIT:**
Looking at your code I can see you aren't actually using composer. Sure you might be including the libraries but you aren't setting up any of the functions required for it to work.

I suggest you read this article: [Introducing the Composer API](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/). This will guide you through the use of composer.

At the very least you should have the following functions for composer to work.

- scene:create()
- scene:show()
- scene:hide()
- scene:delete()

And within those utilize the the scene's view using `local sceneGroup = self.view`. Once objects been inserted into this properly you can have “manage” your scene and the display objects within.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for ur reply.
So, my concern now is i have zero idea of where to put my code..
Now, i've already put in all the backgrounds,mosquito,bee,timetext in the function create. i insert them into sceneGroup, i added eventListener.

so, where should i put or how to keep spawning mosquitoes and bees? 
How to set the countdown timer? 
Where should i put all these codes?

Comment: You can put all the code inside the create. Only thing you need to remember is to add display objects to the sceneGroup/Scene view.